# How to set build commands in geany for compiling c++ files with wsl?

Tags: c++, cp

I installed geany and wsl (Ubuntu) for competitive programming. I've noticed that unlike Linux there is no terminal for geany in windows. I like to know if there is a way to get terminal in geany for windows version and also is there a way to set build commands in geany to compile c++ files with wsl.

Comment: do you mean there is no terminal in geany in windows or in the wsl itself?

Comment: no terminal for geany in windows

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to set build commands in geany so that it will compile c++ files with wsl

Answer (score 0):

1. Install gcc in your wsl(Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt install g++
```

2. Config Geany

```
Build: wsl gcc -Wall -o "%e" "%f"
Execute: wsl "./%e"
```